# how to use kohana 3.3 Route::url get urls end with a slash "/"?

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3, kohana-3.3

the route setting:

```
Route::set('movie', '<id>(/<action>.htm)', 
    array('id' => '[1-9][0-9]*')
)->defaults(
    array('controller' => 'Movie', 'action' => 'index')
);
```

create a url with Route::url():

```
Route::url('movie', array('id' => 2));
```

then, got a url like:

```
http://www.domain.com/2
```

how get a url end with "/" ?

like this:

```
http://www.domain.com/2/
```

thanks !

Comment: `$url = Route::url('movie', array('id' => 2))."/";`

Comment: Or change the route to `'<id>/(<action>.htm)'`